# How to get excerpt correctly formatted

Tags: excerpt, the-content, line-breaks

I'm using a theme that use `the_excerpt()` function to show the excerpt of the post.

All posts have not set custom excerpt, so `the_excerpt()` returns a piece of post content.

In some post first paragraph contains a `<br>`, for example:

```
<p>My new question is:<br>why words are not separated by a white space?</p>
```

The text rendered is:

```
My new question is:why words are not separated by a white space?
```

Following this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67498/how-to-include-line-breaks-in-the-excerpt) I implemented this solution:

```
function my_excerpt($text = '', $raw_excerpt = '') {
    add_filter('the_content', 'my_content', 6);

    // get through origin filter
    $text = wp_trim_excerpt($text);

    remove_filter('the_content', 'my_content', 6);
    return $text;
}
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'my_excerpt');

function my_content($text)
{
    return str_replace( '<br>', ' ', $text );
}
```

And this works, but I have two questions:

1. Why `the_excerpt()` doesn't substitute `<br>` with space?
2. Is there a better way to achieve this result?

Also, I'm quite new to wordpress development, any suggestions to improve my code are welcome.

**Update**:
I found that is reported this [issue](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/15117), but unfortunately is still open.

Comment: Why would it substitute with a space? That would break things in some situations

Comment: @TomJNowell In the page that show article with a little piece of text (like categories or post per years) sentence are showed in a messed way, like the example above. So I want that when the excerpt is automatically generated from content, it is rendered in a correct way. Did you think that my code can break things? could you explain when and why? Thanks

Comment: Whitespace would make sense to me too. I think it'd be better to change wp_strip_all_tags to add the whitespace though and leave the_excerpt alone. There's probably other cases e.g. if there was no whitespace in the markup when one paragraph ends and another starts e.g. 'abc</p><p>def', and other versions of br e.g. `<br/>`, `<br />` - or with any attribute too really - but simple `<br>` is probably the most common..

Comment: @Rup thanks. I see where is the problem. wp_strip_all_tags use php function strip_tags that remove alla html tag and generate messy excerpt both in case of br and in case of </p><p>. Probably classic editor put white space before br and at the end of p tag.  I've used the_content filter that is applied just before text manipulation in wp_trim_excerpt. I should improve my str_replace to keep other br as you point out. Could you help me? Something like: <br>|<br/>|<br />? I'm not very good with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

`wp_trim_excerpt()` calls `wp_trim_words()` which applies `wp_strip_all_tags()` to the excerpt. The `<br>` tag is removed and not replaced with anything.

Not sure if this is feasible, but having a space after a colon is grammatically correct, and adding it to the original content would not affect the HTML, e.g.:

`<p>My new question is: <br>why words are not separated by a white space?</p>`

Comment: thanks for the reply, although it might be a way around this, I should always check that there is space before SHIFT + RETURN, because in the editor space at the end of sentence is not visible

Comment: You could always use `&nbsp;` for the space too

Comment: In the gutemberg editor I can't use it, I should edit HTML, but often writers doesn't know it... anyway +1 for your effort, thanks